# How to create Folder in Sugar Sync IOS ?

Tags: ios, iphone

I can able to create a folder inside the folder by passing the folder id . To create the folder inside another folder,SDK is returning id . example: https://api.sugarsync.com/folder/:sc:566494:4

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""https://api.sugarsync.com/folder/:sc:566494:4];
[[SugarSyncClient getSharedInstance]createFolderNamed:@"Test" parentFolderURL:url completionHandler:^(NSURL * newFolderUrl, NSError * error){
}];
```

I need to create a folder in root directory.Here what i need to pass to create the folder in root directory.

Comment: Have you got any solution. I am facing same issue.